# Adding php condition in css file

Tags: php, css

I am new to coding. I am trying to add below condition to my css but it doesnt work. If any one can help. Below is the code I am inserting into my css.

Basically I am trying that if the post type equals 'event' only then this css should apply to that post type.

```
<?php if (get_post_type($_post) == 'event' ) { ?>
.apus-breadscrumb .wrapper-breads {
    min-height: 300px !important; }
    max-height: 300px !important;
    }
<?php   } ?>
```

Comment: css file as  myfile.css   don't executed php ..

Comment: Instead you can add a class (ie "event") to the html element in php. Then write  css targeting that element

Comment: Did you change the file extension to `.php`?

Comment: No actually I am trying to apply that css for only that posts_type.

Comment: You can save the file as. Php and add the if condition. Then it would work

Comment: Don't listen to @Akin. 
Style post types using css classes, then conditionally assign class to post.

Comment: The problem is the same class is available in every post type.. But I want to apply the css when the same class is available on a specific post type only.

Comment: @AtharK Did you get any point?

Comment: @Rathinam as far as I remember, I solved this using javascript or jquery.